# The relation between the integration on concentric hypercubes

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-measure

In $R^n$, $Q$ is a hypercube that can be in anywhere in $R^n$. $MQ$ is the concentric hypercube with $Q$, and its radius is M times of the radius of $Q$.How to prove that there exists a constant C that only depends on n such that:$$\int_{MQ}\frac{1}{|x|}dx\leq C\int_Q \frac{1}{|x|}dx, \forall Q \ \ \text{in $R^n$}$$
I don't know how to prove $C$ is independent of $Q$. It is easy to prove that when $Q$ is centered at original point, $C=M^{n-1}$. But for other cases, I have no idea.
In addition, $n>1,M>1$, $|x|$ is the Euclidean norm of $x$. Maybe the polar coordinates are helpful.

Comment: May I ask what is cubic and concentric cubic? I know only cubic polynomial. Are they related?

Comment: The cubic in $R^n$ here means each side is an interval.

Comment: I still do not understand, side of what is interval?

Comment: Q's every side is an interval. For example, when n=3, Q=[a, b]*[c, d]*[e,f]. Q is the simple cube.

Comment: I think you want to use the word "hypercube" instead of "cubic"!

Comment: @Gerry Myerson.  Yes, you are right. I should use "hypercube" rather than "cubic".

Comment: It is said that this problem comes from the computation mathematics